# ionic 3 - Error at FatalException.Exception - bug in the new version?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, fatal-error, ionic3

I downloaded Ionic 3 few days ago and everything worked just fine when all of the sudden yesterday this error showed up after every ionic command I tried to use (ionic info, ionic serve, ionic start etc.):

> { Error
>       at FatalException.Exception (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\errors.js:8:23)
>       at FatalException (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\errors.js:17:9)
>       at Config. (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\config.js:41:31)
>       at throw (native)
>       at rejected (C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\config.js:5:65)
>   name: 'Exception', exitCode: 1, fatal: true }

I have tried to delete ionic and cordova and reinstall many times using many different instructions I found online:

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic
npm cache clean -f
npm install npm -g
npm uninstall node
apt-get purge npm
apt-get install npm
npm install node -g
```

I've also tried to delete and reinstall node but this error stay with every version of ionic 3.X.X I tried. ionic 2 on the other hand work great. any Idea what might have caused that and how to fix it?

I'm using:

- Windows 10
- npm : 4.6.1
- node: v6.10.3
- cordova: 7.0.1

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a known issue [1](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/2334), you might be able to work around it by getting a copy of a peer's config.json file. Alternatively, you could try wiping out your %userprofile%.ionic folder and redoing the ionic install.

[Error at FatalException.Exception bug](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/2334)

Answer (score 6):

Deleting the config.json file from C:\Users{your_user}.ionic did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this C:\UsersUSER.ionic folder and then uninstall ionic and then  reinstall ionic with npm install -g ionic

Answer (score 0):

First you delete the 'C:\UsersUSER.ionic folder, then dlete/uninstall ionic! then reinstall ionic cordova
This worked for me